# IIS application binding

Tags: asp.net, iis

I have two domain names:

sub1.example.com
sub2.example.com

In IIS I have a:

```
WEBSITE[SUB1]

   Content

   APPLICATION[SUB2]
```

I want to have sub1.example.com display the content of the site SUB1 and sub2.example.com to display the content of the application SUB2. How do I achieve it with IIS bindings? I've not been able to figure it out.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I do not think this is possible with bindings. Bindings are used to associate a domain with a *Website* not an *Application*.

A possible solution would be to create a second Website pointing to the just the Application folder (a little intuitive perhaps if SUB2 is inside SUB1 because may be able to get to SUB2 via the SUB1 domain unless you add restrictions), but then you would be able to bind *sub2.example.com* to the second website and have it display the content of application SUB2 as desired.

Cheers